# Trying to put an Array into JSONObject

Tags: android, json, serialization

I'm trying to convert Java class to JSONObject and It works but with a little issue. When I put an arraylist object into a JSONObject it saves it among quotes.

This is a problem for me because when I try to do the deserialization it detects it's a string and not an array.

This is the class where I receive the data from the json api:

```
public class IndicadorEconomico {
    @SerializedName("version")
    private String version;
    @SerializedName("autor")
    private String autor;
    @SerializedName("codigo")
    private String codigo;
    @SerializedName("nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @SerializedName("unidad_medida")
    private String unidad_medida;
    @SerializedName("serie")
    private ArrayList<Object> serie;

    private static final String JSON_VERSION = "version";
    private static final String JSON_AUTOR = "autor";
    private static final String JSON_CODIGO = "codigo";
    private static final String JSON_NOMBRE = "nombre";
    private static final String JSON_UNIDAD_MEDIDA = "unidad_medida";
    private static final String JSON_SERIE = "serie";

    public JSONObject convertToJSON() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();

        jo.put(JSON_VERSION, version);
        jo.put(JSON_AUTOR, autor);
        jo.put(JSON_CODIGO, codigo);
        jo.put(JSON_NOMBRE, nombre);
        jo.put(JSON_UNIDAD_MEDIDA, unidad_medida);
        jo.put(JSON_SERIE, serie);

        Log.e("info", "" + jo.toString());

        return jo;
    }
}
```

And this is the JSONSerializer class where I make the serialization process:

```
public class JSONSerializer 

{

    private static final String TAG = JSONSerializer.class.getSimpleName();

    private String mFilename;
    private Context mContext;

    public JSONSerializer(String fn, Context con) {
        this.mFilename = fn;
        this.mContext = con;
    }

    public void save(IndicadorEconomico indicadorEconomico) throws IOException, JSONException {
        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            OutputStream out = mContext.openFileOutput(mFilename, mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
            writer.write(indicadorEconomico.convertToJSON().toString());
        } finally {
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to do same with ease